# Call static method from generic type

Tags: c#, generics, methods, static

I has static class with generic argument which declared like this:

```
public static partial class CMSLib<TUser> where TUser : CMSLib<TUser>.UserBase
{
    public abstract class UserBase : OrmObject<TUser>
    {
        public UInt32 Id { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        /* etc. */
    }
}
```

`OrmObject` declared like this:

```
public abstract class OrmObject<T> where T: class
{
    static OrmObject()
    {
        using (var db = Db.Open())
            db.CreateTable<T>();
    }

    public static T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where) { ... }
}
```

When i trying call method **Single** from generic parameter:

```
public static partial class CMSLib<TUser> where TUser : CMSLib<TUser>.UserBase
{
    public static TUser SomeFunction()
    {
        var user = TUser.Single(...); // Here error
        ...
    }
}
```

I got error **'TUser' is a 'type parameter', which is not valid in the given context**

How in this case i can call **TUser.Single** method (static constructor in `OrmObject` must be called)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `OrmObject<TUser>.Single()` instead of `TUser.Single()`.